# Calling custom JsonDeserializer from another JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm trying to invoke a custom JsonDeserializer from another one, but I can't figure out how.

I'm using @JsonDeserialize annotations in my entities:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = BobDeserializer.class)
class Bob {

    private Integer number;

    ...

}


@JsonDeserialize(using = AliceDeserializer.class)
class Alice {

    private Bob bob;

    ...

}
```

My deserializers are:

```
class BobDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Bob> {

    public Bob deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);

        Integer number = node.get("number").asInt();

        Bob bob = new Bob();
        bob.setNumber(number);

        return bob;
    }

}


class AliceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Alice> {

    public Alice deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);

        Bob bob = ???????; // How to get Bob calling BobDeserializer to deserialize node.get("bob")?

        Alice alice = new Alice();
        alice.setBob(bob);

        return alice;
    }

}
```

AliceDeserializer receives a JSON input like the following:

```
{
    "bob": {
        "number": 2
    }
}
```

I need help invoking BobDeserializer from AliceDeserializer. **I want to use an automatic mechanism** for this, instead of injecting the deserializer using @Autowired.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when writing a custom deserializer you need to make sure anything you can serialize with the `ObjectMapper` instead of actually parsing every field by itself. Once you do that, the `ObjectMapper` will automatically call the deserializer of an object if exists.

And the code:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = BobDeserializer.class)
class Bob {

    private Integer number;

    public Bob() {
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = AliceDeserializer.class)
public class Alice {
    private Bob bob;

    public Alice() {
    }

    public Bob getBob() {
        return bob;
    }

    public void setBob(Bob bob) {
        this.bob = bob;
    }
}

class BobDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Bob> {

    protected BobDeserializer() {
        super(Bob.class);
    }

    public Bob deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);

        Integer number = node.get("number").asInt();

        Bob bob = new Bob();
        bob.setNumber(number);

        return bob;
    }
}

class AliceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Alice> {

    protected AliceDeserializer() {
        super(Alice.class);
    }

    public Alice deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Bob bob = mapper.readValue(node.get("bob").toString(), Bob.class);

        Alice alice = new Alice();
        alice.setBob(bob);

        return alice;
    }
}
```

And deserializing test code:

```
Alice alice = new Alice();
Bob bob = new Bob();
bob.setNumber(3);
alice.setBob(bob);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Alice alice1 = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(alice), Alice.class);
```

Comment: I knew about ObjectMapper, but I couldn't figure out how to use readValue with a JsonNode. It was as simple as calling toString. Thanks