# Use a jackson deserializer inside another jackson deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've created a custom deserializer for my DigitalInput and Resource classes.

DigitalInput contains a `List<Resource>`.

So I need to use my custom `ResourceDeserializer` inside my `DigitalInputDeserializer`, and I don't know how to do that.

```
public class DigitalInputDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DigitalInput> {

    @Override
    public DigitalInput deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        DigitalInput digitalInput = null;

        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        Date timestamp = Instant.parse(node.get("timestamp").asText()).toDate();
        String matter = node.get("matter").asText();
        String description = node.get("comment").asText();
        //...

        JsonNode resources = node.get("resources");
        //???

        return digitalInput;
    }
}
```

So, as you can guess, resources is a json array. In order to deserialize a `Resource` I've implemented a `ResourceDeserializer` and I want to use it here.

What can I do?
Thanks for all.

Comment: Did you ever discover how to solve this? Would be really glad if you could post a solution.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394370/calling-custom-jsondeserializer-from-another-jsondeserializer)